# Several decimal for double in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, double, decimal

I create XML with JAXB, and I want to put double inside tags:

```
@XmlElement(name = "TaxFree")
private double taxFreeValue;
```

When I set value with `setTaxFreeValue(4.5);` in tags shows `<TaxFree>4.5<TaxFree>`

Is it possible in JAXB to get this  `<TaxFree>4.500<TaxFree>` without transfer double to string?

Comment: For double values `4.5 == 4.500`. So I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I need this format 4.500 in XML tags, I know that is value same.

Comment: What about creating a wrapper class that changes the field to Strings and back again.

Comment: Thanks, that can be solution, but if JAXB have some annotation witch create this format?

Comment: If you have another program that consumes this XML, and that program requires `4.500` and cannot deal with `4.5` then I suggest that program is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` to convert from the double value to the desired text (String) representation.

- [Using JAXB generated class for an element that requires an integer with a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182533/using-jaxb-generated-class-for-an-element-that-requires-an-integer-with-a-patter/7194004#7194004)

Comment: Thanks, you have great blog for learning and answers here about JAXB.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is this

```
double taxFreeValue;

@XmlElement(name = "TaxFree")
private String getTaxFree() {
    return String.format("%.3f", taxFreeValue);
}
```

Note that you can give this method any name and make it private JAXB dont care as soon as the annotation is present.

Comment: Worked for me, if anyone has problems, make sure to check the `@XmlAccessorType` of your class. I have it on `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so marshalling that it only takes into account `@XmlElement` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way I've found is to use `XMLAdapter`. Create a `DoubleAdapter` class with:

```
public class DoubleAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Double> {
    @Override
    public Double unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null || v.isEmpty() || v.equals("null")) {
            return null;
        }
        return Double.parseDouble(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Double v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        //Edit the format to your needs
        return String.format("%.3f", v);
    }
}
```

To use it, simply add the annotation.

```
@XmlElement(name = "TaxFree")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DoubleAdapter.class)
private double taxFreeValue;
```