# XJC restriction convert Double to String

Tags: java, xsd, xjc, xml-binding

i read XML by generated `javax.xml.bind`-Annotated classes from XSD.

```
<xsd:complexType name="foo">
  <xsd:attribute name="bar" type="xsd:double" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

So my class is generated to:

```
public Double getBar(){....}
```

Ok, to ensure a double-Attribute is positive, i use `xsd:restriction`.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="DoublePositive">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
    <xsd:minExclusive value="0" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="foo">
  <xsd:attribute name="bar" type="DoublePositive" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

Too bad, xjc generate a String instead of a Double.

```
public String getBar(){....}
```

Can i Force to use Double instead of String?

### Solution:

My Question was wrong. I had `xsi:type="DoublePositive"`  instead of `type="DoublePositive"`

Comment: maybe you can add custom binding, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568543/how-do-you-specify-the-date-format-used-when-jaxb-marshals-xsddatetime

Comment: principle is the same. You can create binding file and pass to xjc with -b option

Comment: <jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">

        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      parseMethod="parseDate"
                      printMethod="printDate"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

Comment: Generated still String.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182533/using-jaxb-generated-class-for-an-element-that-requires-an-integer-with-a-patter

Comment: I tried it out and xjc (version `JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6`) actually generates an unrestricted Double. No binding file, no adapter, no nothing. Same for version `v2.2.4-2`. What version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my configuration, which i use to generate classes.

1. test.xsd - your xsd file

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace=""
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <xsd:simpleType name="DoublePositive">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:double">
          <xsd:minExclusive value="0"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
      </xsd:simpleType>

      <xsd:complexType name="foo">
        <xsd:attribute name="bar" type="DoublePositive"/>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
   ```
2. text.xml - file with global bindings.

   ```
   <jaxb:bindings version="2.1"
                   xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Double" xmlType="DoublePositive"
                       parseMethod="Converter.fromString"
                       printMethod="Converter.toString"/>
      </jaxb:globalBindings> 
    </jaxb:bindings>
   ```
3. Converter.java - class with conversion functions.

   ```
   public class Converter {
     public static Double fromString(String str){
       return Double.parseDouble(str);
     }

     public static String toString(Double value){
       return String.valueOf(value);
     }
   }
   ```

That's all. Call xjc with command

`xjc -b test.xml -classpath . test.xsd`.

```
$ xjc -version
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10" 
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB 2.1.10)
$ xjc -b test.xml -classpath . test.xsd 
parsing a schema... 
[WARNING] EmptyTargetNamespace: In schema document 'file:/pwd/test.xsd', the
value of the 'targetNamespace' attribute cannot be an empty string.  
line 3 of file:/pwd/test.xsd

compiling a schema... 
generated/Adapter1.java
generated/Foo.java
generated/ObjectFactory.java
```

and generated file content:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    protected Double bar;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the bar property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public Double getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the bar property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setBar(Double value) {
        this.bar = value;
    }

}
```

and Adapter class

```
package generated;

import java.util.Double;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class Adapter1
    extends XmlAdapter<String, Double>
{


    public Double unmarshal(String value) {
        return (Converter.fromString(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Double value) {
        return (Converter.toString(value));
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, xjc generates the classes correctly. If you still get a `String`, then maybe you forgot to add something in your configuration. But without the details about your configuration, it is impossible to say what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Still String after `maven clean install`. Should the `text.xml` not be named `bindings.xjb`?

Comment: it can be named as you like. I used file names from my old test project.

Comment: Still String after rename to `bindings.xjb`. Sorry.