# Jaxb conversion of number with comma as a decimal separator

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using Jaxb to parse xml. In the xml file I have list of items defined as follows:

```
<item>
   <currency_name>US Dollar</currency_code>
   <currency_code>USD</currency_code>
   <rate>3,0223</rate>
</item>
```

When I put in my xsd file the following line:

```
<xsd:element name="rate" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

I get 3,0223 as a string value, however when I put:

```
<xsd:element name="rate" type="xsd:double/BigDecimal/float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

then I recieve 0.0/null.
I think that the problem is in the "," separator.
How to unmarshall rate value to BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are generating your model from XML Schema, below is an approach you can use to cause an `XmlAdapter` to be generated for your use case.

**Formatter Object**

You will need to create a class with methods that can convert the string to/from `BigDecimal`.

```
public class BigDecimalFormatter {

    public static String printBigDecimal(BigDecimal value) {
        // TODO - Conversion logic
    }

    public static BigDecimal parseBigDecimal(String value) {
        // TODO - Conversion logic
    }

}
```

**External Bindings Document (bindings.xml)**

An external binding document is used to specify that your custom conversion class should be used when converting the XML string to/from your `BigDecimal` property.

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='rate']">
            <jxb:property>
                <jxb:baseType>
                    <jxb:javaType name="java.math.BigDecimal"
                        parseMethod="forum20711223.BigDecimalFormatter.parseBigDecimal" printMethod="forum20711223.BigDecimalFormatter.printBigDecimal" />
                </jxb:baseType>
            </jxb:property>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**XJC Call**

The `-b` flag is used to reference the external binding document.

```
xjc -b binding.xml schema.xsd
```

**Full Example**

- [Using JAXB generated class for an element that requires an integer with a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182533/using-jaxb-generated-class-for-an-element-that-requires-an-integer-with-a-patter/7194004#7194004)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. You saved my day! ;)
However I think that there should be java.math.BigDecimal instead of BigInteger, but that's only a small detail.

Comment: @Adam - I'm happy I could help.  I have fixed that one `BigInteger`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it only with code in java? In my case, the classes generated from the schema are given by an external source.