# XSD schema string elements Encrypt/Decrypt

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, castor

How could I make the XSD schema string element(password) as type encrypted, This in turn would be used in XSD to java code generator encrypt and decrypt during Writing/Reading process of XML not just validation.

Does any XSD to java class generator provide this feature ??

Cheers,
Reddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` to control how the data is converted between XML and Java.  This `XmlAdapter` is used to hook in your own encryption logic.

Below is a link to an answer I gave that demonstrates how to create an `XmlAdapter` when generating the model from XML Schema.

- [Using JAXB generated class for an element that requires an integer with a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182533/using-jaxb-generated-class-for-an-element-that-requires-an-integer-with-a-patter/7194004#7194004)